# How can I set the caller ID with Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts, voip

When calling with Google Hangout, how can I set the caller ID, the number that recipient of my phone call sees? Is it even possible at all to set it?

Now it's showing a US number when I call my own mobile phone but I'd like it to show one of my European phone numbers.

With Skype I can even make it show different numbers for different countries. I'd love to have this for hangout.